# Gremlin: project all labels and count of each

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I currently have a query that gives me the count of each label:
`g.V().group().by(label).by(count())`

However this is resulting in a column for each label. I want to project two columns "Entity Type" and "Count" and count the number of each label. So far, this is all I have but it is incorrect:

```
g.V().project('Entity Type','Count')
.by(label)
.by(groupCount())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `group().by(label).by(count)` can be simplified to `groupCount().by(label)`.

To reshape the result you only need a simple projection:

```
g.V().
  groupCount().
    by(label).
  unfold().
  project('Entity Type','Count').
    by(keys).
    by(values)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. you rock!